# How to use V8::AddMemoryAllocationCallback method in C++ NodeJS Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, callback, v8, node.js-addon

I'm trying to use [V8::AddMemoryAllocationCallback](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1V8.html#ac9718f8dc3f3c498bf07282eb7c1618e) method for a NodeJS C++ Addon. I want to call to that method and return that size value. I came up with following code. Seems to be it's not calling to callback method.
The code is taken form [goingnative](https://github.com/workshopper/goingnative/tree/master/exercises/call_me_maybe/solution) npm module.

But the `memCallback` method didn't get trigger. Why? How to fix it?

It'll use the following C++ code to access V8 library.

```
//myaddon.cc
#include <nan.h>
# include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace v8;

static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;

void memCallback(ObjectSpace space, AllocationAction action, int size)   {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("/tmp/example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();

    x = size;
}

NAN_METHOD(Delay) {
  NanScope();

  int delay = args[0].As<Number>()->IntegerValue();
  Local<Function> callback = args[1].As<Function>();

  V8::AddMemoryAllocationCallback(&memCallback, kObjectSpaceNewSpace, kAllocationActionAllocate);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    y = i;
    Local<Value> argv[] = {NanNew(x), NanNew(y)};
    NanMakeCallback(NanGetCurrentContext()->Global(), callback, 2, argv);
    usleep(delay * 1000);
  }

  NanReturnUndefined();
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(NanNew("delay"), NanNew<FunctionTemplate>(Delay)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(myaddon, Init)
```

node-gyp has use to build and run the code (try `node-gyp rebuild && node index.js 1000 && ls /tmp/` from current folder)

```
//binding.gyp
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "myaddon",
      "sources": [ "myaddon.cc" ],
      "include_dirs": [ "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Following is the JavaScript code. I have created few variables in order to allocate some memory.

```
//index.js
var addon = require('bindings')('myaddon')

addon.delay(process.argv[2], function(x, y) {
    console.log("X: ", x, " Y:", y);

    var arr = [], obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arr.push("Text " + i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        obj[i] = arr[i];
        delete arr[i];
    }
    console.log('Done!');
})

console.log("The End");
```

Current output is;

```
X:  0  Y: 0
Done!
X:  0  Y: 1
Done!
X:  0  Y: 2
Done!
X:  0  Y: 3
Done!
X:  0  Y: 4
Done!
X:  0  Y: 5
Done!
X:  0  Y: 6
Done!
X:  0  Y: 7
Done!
X:  0  Y: 8
Done!
X:  0  Y: 9
Done!
The End
```

Comment: The `AddMemoryAllocationCallback()` callback might be called in the main thread, so currently you are blocking that thread by sleeping in the for loop. If you remove the loop, do you see the `example.txt` being written to?

Comment: @mscdex I removed `for loop` and `usleep`. But I can't see a `example.txt`. Do you thing that my code is well written (any syntax errors) ? I'm not sure about `V8::AddMemoryAllocationCallback(&memCallback, kObjectSpaceNewSpace, kAllocationActionAllocate);` Or `V8::AddMemoryAllocationCallback(memCallback, kObjectSpaceNewSpace, kAllocationActionAllocate);`. How to add function reference?

Comment: Did you try other arguments like `kObjectSpaceAll` instead of `kObjectSpaceNewSpace` and/or `kAllocationActionAll` instead of `kAllocationActionAllocate`?

Comment: @mscdex Here we go. After changing into `kObjectSpaceAll` and `kAllocationActionAll` , now it's working. Thank you very much! One more question. How can I get `size` value into `Delay` method ? Seems to be global variable isn't change as expected. May be callback is running on another worker. So, how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using less limiting notification settings may help (`kObjectSpaceAll` instead of `kObjectSpaceNewSpace` and/or `kAllocationActionAll` instead of `kAllocationActionAllocate`).

For passing `size` to your callback, here's couple ways to go about it:

- First, you might consider using an EventEmitter instead of a callback since the `memCallback` will be called many times, unless you really only want callbacks to fire for the next `memCallback` invocation. With the EventEmitter solution you would only register a JS callback once in C++ land, which would get stored globally and would get called inside `memCallback`. Then in JS land, you would just emit an event when your JS callback is executed.

  You could even tweak that so that the JS callback (and maybe even the C++ callback) only stays registered in C++ land if there are listeners for your event (EventEmitter provides events to notify you when listeners are added and removed for an event). This might help improve performance.
- If you really want to use callbacks that get executed multiple times (which really goes against general expectations in the node community), then you will have to both store the JS callbacks in a global C++ array structure of some kind *and* provide some way to "unregister" JS callbacks so they don't get called anymore (would remove the JS callback from the C++ array).

Comment: I'm agree with you suggestion. So, you are suggesting something like https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-event-emitter (It would be great, if it's a NAN example). But I can't understand that why is that `x` value does not get changed. Did I something wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: I need to send these values (`size`) for every 100ms to JS and reset it. Even through `memCallback` will call in smaller intervals, I want to make sure that those details pass into JS for every 100ms.